# Solving for limit of integration of a linear equation

Tags: integration

Given:

$$A = \int_c^d (mx+b)\,dx$$

I'm trying to solve for c and I'm getting stuck, it keeps coming out rather complicated.

I get this down to:
$$A = \frac{1}{2}(mc^2 - md^2) + b(c-d)$$
if I'm doing this correctly.

Is this solvable? I'd think this sort of problem for a straight line would be, but I'm not so savvy.

Comment: You can find $c$ only if you know $A, b, d \, $ and $m$.

Comment: if you are integration in some region $x\in[c,d]$ i.e. $c\le x\le d$ some function $f(x)$ where $F'(x)=f(x)$ then we would say this integral is defined by $F(d)-F(c)$ so in your case the signs are the wrong way round, think of it as the top limit subbed in minus the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should specify the variable with respect to which you are integrating. In this case you are integrating with respect to $x$ so you should write $A=\int_c^d (mx+b) dx$.

When evaluating an integral $\int_c^d f(x)dx$ where the antiderivative of $f$ is $F$, the value of the integral is $F(d)-F(c)$ by the second fundamental theorem of calculus. So the signs you have need to be reversed.

Now what we get is $(\frac{m}{2})c^2+(b)c+(-\frac{md^2}{2}-bd+A)=0$. This is a polynomial of degree 2 in c, so we can solve it using the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

it is a second degree equation:

$
\frac{1}{2}mc^2+bc-\frac{1}{2}md^2-bd+A=0
$

(You have wrong signs)

Comment: Thanks for the hint and the signs! I'm doing this for a personal project. I get that this is quadratic but I don't know how to incorporate the extra factors that involve d into the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment, if we correct the signs and integrate we get:
$$A=\frac m2\left(d^2-c^2\right)+b(d-c)$$
we can view this as a quadratic equation which we are solving for c:
$$A=-\frac m2c^2-bc+\frac{md^2}2+bd$$
which we can rewrite as:
$$\left(\frac m2\right)c^2+(b)c+\left(A-bd-\frac{md^2}{2}\right)=0$$
which is an equation of the form:
$$\alpha x^2+\beta x+\gamma=0\Rightarrow x=\frac{-\beta\pm\sqrt{\beta^2-4\alpha\gamma}}{2\alpha}$$
and there is your solution, obviously you would need to know all of the values apart from $c$ in order to work out these factors $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$

Answer (score 0):

Evaluation of integral  proceeds upper limit minus lower limit, so sign of A should be changed. Since there is a $c^2$ term and a $c$ term, it is a quadratic equation.

$$-A=\frac m2\left(c^2-d^2\right)+b(c-d)$$

If the constants are bracketed together letting

$$B=(A-md^2/2--bd)\quad \rightarrow  \frac{mc^2}{2}+bc+B=0\;$$
has two roots
$$mc= -b\pm\sqrt{b^2-2mB} $$

When area $A$ under a straight line is sketched against $x$ it would be found to be the same ( as  positive and negative parts of area cancel out) at the above two $x$ values.